# jqgrid paging without caching

Tags: jqgrid, paging

I need to a scroll paging with jqgrid where I query the database each time the user scrolls the vertical bar.

Is this possible with jqgrid? If so, I would like to see a simple example.

Comment: Look at [the official demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) in "New in version 3.6" / "True scrolling Rows" and "New in version 3.7" / "Virtual scrolling"

Comment: thanks Oleg. Can you put this as an answer please so I cam mark it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) conttains the examples under "New in version 3.6" / "True scrolling Rows" and "New in version 3.7" / "Virtual scrolling".